# How to pause or stop currently playing audio that is not from my app, from background?

Tags: audio, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, background-task

I want to pause and/or stop background audio that is currently playing on the phone (this audio being from other apps). And I want to do this from a background task, when my app is not running/visible.

There are about 1000 apps in the store that can be used to stop the currently playing audio - but these apps need to stay open all the time. And they tend to be buggy on Windows 10.

So there are actually two questions:

1. How do these other apps stop the audio (that is not their own) **pre** Windows 10 Mobile (e.g. on Windows Phone 8/8.1)?
2. How can I pause and/or stop audio (that is currently playing and not my own) in Windows 10 Mobile **latest** (>= Anniversary update)?

There have been extensions of the background process and audio model in Windows 10 so I'm hoping for new possibilities here.

Comment: Could you share a store app that can achieve what you said? I don't think there is an API can achieve this as UWP apps are running in app containers which are isolated from each other.

Comment: @zorro Sure, here are some: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/stop-music/9nblggh0ccfd https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/stop-music/9nblggh086wn https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/stop-music-plus/9nblggh0852t - I think they stop the playback by removing the played song from the "system player" somehow. And they need to be running in the foreground/ under the lock screen to do this. Don't know how it works, though - thats part 1 of the question.